# Anorm replacement of params gives error on usage of aggregate functions

Tags: scala, anorm, sql-parser

Table structure -

```
create table test
(month integer,
year integer,
thresholds decimal(18,2)
);
```

Static insert for simulation -

```
insert into test(month,year,threshold) values(4,2021,100),(5,2021,98),(6,2021,99);
```

If I query `postgres` database using `anorm`, it works for regular queries. However on adding aggregate functions like `max`, the `RowParser` is not able to find the alias column.

```
val queryString =
  """select max(month) as monthyear from test
     | where (month || '-' || year)
     | = {inQuery}""".stripMargin

    val inQuery1 = "'5-2021'"
```

The below `on` method causes the issue -

```
val latestInBenchmark = SQL(queryString).on("inQuery" -> inQuery1) // removing the on resolves the problem

logger.info("query for latest period ---> " + latestInBenchmark)

val latestYearMonthInInterval = database.withConnection(implicit conn => {
          latestInBenchmark.as(SqlParser.int("monthyear").*)
        })
```

Removing the `on` rectifies the problem and `SqlParser.int(column-name)` works as expected.
This also does not affect queries that use `count` aggregate function.

Error encountered :

```
(Validated intervals with sorting -> ,Failure(anorm.AnormException: 'monthyear' not found, available columns: monthyear, monthyear))
[error] c.b.ThresholdController - 'monthyear' not found, available columns: monthyear, monthyear
```

Comment: You should never ever use string interpolation with parameter, please first read the documentation

Comment: Maybe OP changed the post in the meantime but there's no string interpolation in here.

Comment: It happens without the string interpolation. It was a copy-paste error, since I used string interpolation to workaround the Anorm parameter error

Answer (score -1):

The error you have is a bit misleading but it means the query either returns a row with a null value or no row.

In your case I think the issue is the `WHERE` clause: you have put single quotes around the value but Anorm will do it by itself when using `.on(...)` or Anorm interpolation.

Thus, replace:

```scala
val inQuery1 = "'5-2021'"
```

By:

```scala
val inQuery1 = "5-2021"
```

Comment: The sql works and returns a row. Tried removing the single-quotes, but gives me the same error.

Comment: @ForeverLearner, then I'd try to debug what's going on in the response parsing. You should be able to have access to the raw data returned by the query and maybe understand the error.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/#passing-parameters), there are many examples how to pass parameters, clearly denoting you must not quote by yourself. As any decently typed lib, Anorm expect an `Option[T]` if you want to pass a nullable `T`.